# Working with DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem - transform to Enumerable Object?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, datagridview, databound

I have a DataGridView with

```
myGridView.DataSource = GetSomeData()


// method called
public IQueryable GetSomeData()
{
    var source = from r in records
                 select r;

    return source;    // made correction from 'r' to 'source'
}
```

`GetSomeData()` fills the DataGridView as expected. The user will select a row to edit which then passes the row data to a form. Since the `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem` is an anonymous type, how can I pass `DataBoundItem`?

I half expected that my DataBoundItem would be IQueryable - incorrect. Here is the info from the debugger on the DataBoundItem property:

> DataBoundItem { CustomerID = "3133",
>   Last_Name = "Smith", First_Name =
>   "John", AccountNumber = "JS3133",
>   ActiveYN = True } < Anonymous Type >

Once the data is passed to the new form, I would like to do something like:

```
txtFName.Text = SomeEnumeratedObject["First_Name"];
txtLName.Text = SomeEnumeratedObject["Last_Name"];
```

Any ideas on how I can do this? It would be even better, IMO, if the controls on the new form could some how be bound to `SomeEnumeratedObject`.

Would it possible to query the `DataBoundItem` with LINQ?

### Edit:

Changed method:

```
public DataView GetSomeData()
{
    var source = from r in records
                 select r;

    DataTable table = ToDataTable(myContext, source);
    return new DataView(table);
}
```

See complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149040/working-with-datagridviewrow-databounditem-transform-to-enumerable-object/4150549#4150549).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it as `dynamic` and access the properties that way:

```
public void Test(dynamic item)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} : {1}", item.First_Name, item.Last_Name));
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _item, "First_Name");
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", _item, "Last_Name");
}
```

One thing to consider is that properties on anonymous types are read only, so your user will not be able to edit the values that way.  From the C# Language Spec:

> The members of an anonymous type are a sequence of read-only properties inferred from the anonymous object initializer used to create an instance of the type.

You should consider declaring a type for this instead of using an anonymous type.  That way you'll also get the benefit of intellisense and be able to rename/refactor your properties without any problems.

Comment: @dboarman, in that case, I think you should declare a class to use for displaying/editing this information.  As mentioned, an anonymous type is read-only, so you wouldn't be able to use data-binding to capture changes.

Comment: I think the best class for this is going to be the DataTable. I don't really think I need to define a new class. The DataTable is flexible and can be transformed (via DataView) for use as a DataSource, which means I should be able to cast a DataBoundItem to a DataRow...

Answer (score 1):

What type of objects are in records?  You should be able to cast DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem to whatever type of object records holds.

Say records is a list of Customer objects. You should be able to go:

```
txtFName.Text = ((Customer)DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem).First_Name;
txtLName.Text = ((Customer)DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem).Last_Name;
```

If that isn't possible, then I think you will have to use reflection:

```
Type type = DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem.GetType();  
String firstName = (String)type.GetProperty("First_Name")
                        .GetValue(DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem, null);
```

Comment: The DataBoundItem is an Anonymous type. The records in the DGV are retrieved from a LINQ to Sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Both kevev22 & adrift had the right idea: create a class to hold the data. Since I can transform an IQueryable resultset to a DataTable, it only made sense to do that:

```
public DataView GetSomeData()
{
    var source = from r in records
                 select r;

    DataTable table = ToDataTable(myContext, source);
    return new DataView(table);
}
```

Now:

```
myDGView.DataSource = GetSomeData();
```

And, when a datagrid row is selected, you can cast the `DataBoundItem` to `DataRow`.

FYI - to transform an IQueryable resultset to a DataTable:

```
public DataTable ToDataTable(DataContext context, IQueryable source)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = context.GetCommand(source);
        sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
        adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```